# How can I return the "dict" in jsonify in Flask?

Tags: python, for-loop, sqlalchemy, flask-restful

Here is my code:

```
@app.route('/students')
def students():
    list = Student.query.all()
    print(type(list)) #class:list


    studentList2 ={}

    for student in list:
        studentList2= ({'id':student.id,'title':student.title,'email':student.email})
        print(studentList2) # the loop can show student1,2,3 etc. 
    print(type(studentList2)) #class:dict

    print(studentList2) # Only show the last student

    return jsonify(studentList2)
```

The loop can show student1,2,3 etc. But I don't know how to return in JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to return all the student data. `studentList2` in your code is not a `dict`, you need to remove `()`. btw `list` is key word in python, thus do not overwrite it

```
@app.route('/students')
def students():
    lst = Student.query.all()

    studentList2 = []

    for student in lst:
        studentList2.append({'id':student.id,'title':student.title,'email':student.email})
    return jsonify(studentList2)
```

Comment: Thank you, this is the answer i need! I spent for few hours finding the solution already!